# what is NoSxS library

Tags: qt, pyqt4

QT has NoSxS library. I am wondering what is SxS? Should I linked to NoSxS one?

Comment: I'm not sure what NoSxS does, but SxS means side-by-side assembly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly

Comment: If it is indeed referring to side-by-side, then my assumption would be that "NoSxS" is a version of the library compiled without external dependencies to SxS assemblies (which would most likely be MSVC runtime libraries requiring a vcredist installation).